# DOM modify style of a part of textnode directly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

In my JavaScript code I've created dynamically a text node like this:

```
tpu14 = document.createTextNode(numerr+" enhancements that could improve your experience");
```

I've put this Text Node into a  with its formatting.
Now my question is: How can i add directly a style only at "numerr" part without using 2 different div?

Now the result is:

14 enhancements that could improve your experience

I would like to

**14** enhancements that could improve your experience

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp

Comment: This might not be possible using createTextNode
You will have to use innerHTML property
i.e.
var k=document.createElement("span");
k.innerHTML="<b>"+numerr+"</b> enhancements that could improve your experience";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `createTextNode` you could use **[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)** and do this

`element.innerHTML="<b>"+numerr+"</b> enhancements that could improve your experience";`

As suggested in the comments below you could also use **[Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML)**

```
//Usage
// <div id="one">one</div> 
var d1 = document.getElementById('one'); 
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<b>'+numerr+'</b>');

// At this point, the new structure is:
// <div id="one"><b>value</b>one</div>
```

Comment: [element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML="<b>"+numErr+"</b> enhancements that could improve your experience";
```

This should work. Hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML property

```
var k=document.createElement("span"); 
k.innerHTML="<b>"+numerr+"</b> enhancements that could improve your experience";
```